# tikzpicture: use relative position to control the path of line drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[border=80pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[on grid]
\draw [help lines] (0, 0) grid (3, 2);

\node (A) at (0, 0) {A};
\node[above right = 1 and 1 of A] (B) {B};
\node[above right = 1 and 1 of B] (C) {C};
\node[right = 3 of A] (D) {D};

\draw[->] (A) -- (0.8, 0.1) -- (B);
\draw[->] (B) -- (C);
\draw[->] (C) -- (D);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm drawing 4 nodes and 3 lines. When connecting `A` and `B`, I hope the line pass through `(0.8, 01)`, which it does by using `\draw[->] (A) -- (0.8, 0.1) -- (B);`

But tikz fails to parse the coordinate when I use relative position:  `\draw[->] (A) -- [above right = 0.1 and 0.8 of A] -- (B);`. So can I use relative position like `[above right = 0.1 and 0.8 of A]` to control the path of line drawing?

Update:

@Ignasi suggests an interesting solution, which unfortunately I couldn't reproduce using keyword `shift`:

```
\documentclass[border=80pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt, on grid]
\draw [help lines] (0, 0) grid (3, 2);

\node (A) at (0, 0) {A};
\node[above right = 1 and 1 of A] (B) {B};
\node[above right = 1 and 1 of B] (C) {C};
\node[right = 3 of A] (D) {D};

%\draw[->] (A) -- (1, 0) -- (B);
\draw[->] (A) -- ([shift={(0, -1)}]B) -- (B);
\draw[->] (B) -- (C);
\draw[->] (C) -- (D);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this answer may interest you

Comment: A relative coordinate from the pen position is defined with `++(0.8,0.1)`. Use `\draw[->] (A)--++(0.8,0.1)--(B);`

Comment: @Ignasi So it is only possible to refer the last node for relative coordinate?

Comment: @Rahn you could create a dummy node on the coordinate that you want and then refer to it, something like: `\node[above right=0.1 and 0.8 of A, inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (Dummy){};` and then use `(A) - - (Dummy) - - (B);`     But I would use relative coordinates as Ignasi said

Comment: @Jes Thanks! sounds exactly what I want

Comment: @Rahn I'm not sure about what you mean. With `++(x,y)` you refer a relative coordinate from the last position of the pen. But you can use relative coordinates from other nodes with `([shift={(x,y)}]B)`

Comment: @Rahn If you need to define some auxiliar coordinate for further reference, like Jes suggested, i think it's better to use a `coordinate` node instead of a regular `node`. A `coordinate` is just that, a point without dimensions but a `node` has certain size by default and lines will stop at it's border.

Comment: @Ignasi I see. Thanks for the advice but I thought `[on grid]` already configured the node to zero dimensions.

Comment: @Rahn No, `on grid` forces that the distance (positioning)  is measured between node's centers. By default `\node[right = 1cm of A] (B)` implies 1cm distance between right border of `A` and left border of `B`. Remember from your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579827/1952)

Comment: @Ignasi Unfortunately I couldn't get my code working with the keyword `shift`. You may check the updated question.

Comment: @Rahn You're right it was my mistake. You should indicate a coordinate with `shift` not only a node's name. Try with `([shift={(x,y)}]B.center)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `calc` library, then you can refer to the point as `($(A)+(0.8, 0.1)$)`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[on grid]
\draw [help lines] (0, 0) grid (3, 2);

\node (A) at (0, 0) {A};
\node[above right = 1 and 1 of A] (B) {B};
\node[above right = 1 and 1 of B] (C) {C};
\node[right = 3 of A] (D) {D};

\draw[->] (A) -- ($(A)+(0.8, 0.1)$) -- (B);
\draw[->] (B) -- (C);
\draw[->] (C) -- (D);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also use the `calc` library and replace `\draw[->] (A) -- ($(A)+(0.8, 0.1)$) -- (B);` by `\draw[->] (A) -- ($(B)-(0.2, 0.9)$) -- (B);` if you want to define your intermediate point from node B.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=80pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[on grid]
        \draw [help lines] (0, 0) grid (3, 2);
        
        \node (A) at (0, 0) {A};
        \node[above right = 1 and 1 of A] (B) {B};
        \node[above right = 1 and 1 of B] (C) {C};
        \node[right = 3 of A] (D) {D};
        
        \draw[->, red] (A) -| (B);
        \draw[->, green] (A) |- (B);
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know `|-` and `-|` but they don't solve my problem.