# tikzpicture: Freytag’s Pyramid diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to create Freytag’s Pyramid, like the one below. I tried using the code from this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580036/tikzpicture-use-relative-position-to-control-the-path-of-line-drawing) but it does not look close it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What exactly is your question? What part of the code you copied was problematic? Note that on this site you should ask specific questions, for example "How to align text to a path?". The above is really just five coordinates connected by a path and some (sloped) nodes containing text attached to it ...

Comment: I'm trying to create the diagram in Latex and honestly, I don't know where to even start. The code I found works fine, but I need to modify so that the labels are seating above the connecting paths and also show the labels that are below the diagram.

Comment: you didn't have a look at the manual, right? `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={scale=.6}]
\draw (0,0)
--(3,0) node[above,pos=.25]{setting}  
--++(3,3) node[above,pos=.3,sloped]{inciting incident} node[above,pos=.75,sloped]{possible action} node[above]{climax or keypoint}
--++(3,-3) node[above,pos=.5,sloped]{recommendation resolution}
--+(3,0) node[above,pos=.7]{Conclution}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start TikZ drawing with this in mind: putting `node` or `pic` along a `path`. For example,

```
\tikz\draw (0,0) node[left]{$A$}--
           (4,3) node[right]{$B$} 
                 node[pos=.5,sloped,above]{this length is $5$};
```

[image]

Actually, your figure can be draw with only 1 `path` operation (the command `\draw`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{2.5} \def\b{3.4} 
\draw[nodes={scale=.7,magenta},thick] (0,0)
--(\a,0) node[above,pos=.3]{Setting}
node[midway,below=10mm,teal]{Beginning}
node[midway,below=15mm,scale=1.5,teal]{Frame the Story}     
--++(\a,\b) node[above,pos=.25,sloped]{Inciting incident} node[above,pos=.75,sloped]{Possible action} node[above=3mm,teal]{Climax or Keypoint}
node[below=50mm,teal]{Middle}
node[below=55mm,scale=1.5,teal]{Build the Narative}
--++(\a,-\b) node[above,pos=.5,sloped]{recommendation resolution}
--+(\a,0) node[above,pos=.7]{Conclusion}
node[midway,below=10mm,teal]{End}
node[midway,below=15mm,scale=1.5,teal]{Call to Action}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you may like to horizontally align the three nodes in teal color

Comment: Thank you! This is so beautiful

Comment: @jsbibra We can halign it for sure, but in this case, let it a bit sloped along the main path. I can edit if OP really wants to halign